# Recover all rows based on min and max values of a column - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to extract all rows with the min and max value of a specific column.

Here my piece of df:

```
id      time            value
1       16:23:37.006155 406
2       16:23:37.320417 410
3       16:23:37.917598 415
4       16:23:51.049987 420
5       16:23:52.595148 425
6       16:27:13.880722 430
7       16:27:17.258117 435
8       16:28:31.529722 455
9       16:28:37.640527 460
10      16:28:47.782197 405
11      16:28:48.085    410
```

The goal is to create an other df with the time, value columns with these conditions:

- Save the first value
- If the value is inferior of the previous value then save it and the previous too.

So I tried this:

```
df['BeforeDiff'] = df['value'] < df['value'].shift()
```

But I just have the minimums without the first row.

In other terms, I would like the minimums and maximums of each sequence and do the difference with the time column. The result must be:

```
id      time            value
1       16:23:37.006155 406
9       16:28:37.640527 460
10      16:28:47.782197 405
```

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Is there only a first value in your table or are there different first values ​​(id = 1 repeated)?

Comment: It's a little bit unclear to me what you want. Do you simply want first row, row with max value and row with minimum value?

Comment: the time is unique (normal date and time but I simplified the example) and the value of the column value  can be repetead.

This is a time sequence which is repetead, and I need to determine the time between the min and max state (value) to calculate a cadence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `id` in your dataframe is an actual column, and not the index:

```
df.loc[(df['id'] == 1)|(df.value.diff()<0)|((df.value.diff()<0).shift(-1))]

out:
    id  time            value
0   1   16:23:37.006155 406
8   9   16:28:37.640527 460
9   10  16:28:47.782197 405
```